# Select the row based on the specific key

Tags: sql

I have a SQL dataset that looks like this:

```
SourceId  SomeContent   
-------------------
1            aaa        
2            bbb       
3            ccc      
4            ddd    



SourceId ConditionType CondidionValue
-------------------------------
1            1            2
1            2           200
2            1            3
2            2           201
3            1            4
```

I need to select the SourceId that have matching specific key,
e.g. (ConditionType=1 and ConditionValue=2) and (ConditionType=2 and ConditionValue=200 ) should return sourceId = 1). Query with specified key can match only one SourceId.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
SELECT SourceId
  FROM ConditionData
  where ConditionType = 2 and ConditionValue = 200      
  and SourceId  in(
SELECT SourceId 
  FROM ConditionData
  where (ConditionType = 1 and ConditionValue = 2))
```

Is there more elegant query to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation:

```
SELECT  SourceId
FROM    ConditionData
WHERE   (ConditionType = 2 and ConditionValue = 200)
    OR  (ConditionType = 1 and ConditionValue = 2)
GROUP BY SourceId
HAVING  COUNT(1) = 2 -- Alternatively: COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `INNER JOIN` for each condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.SourceId 
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS condition1 ON t1.SourceId = condition1.SourceId AND condition1.ConditionType = 1 AND condition1.CondidionValue = 2
INNER JOIN table2 AS condition2 ON t1.SourceId = condition2.SourceId AND condition2.ConditionType = 2 AND condition2.CondidionValue = 200
```

Comment: @pykpyk if you like it, add +1 to answer

Comment: I did but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."